# Using Euro Sign in factor levels in R

Tags: r, encoding, refactoring, special-characters

Using `R` version 3.2.2 in a `RStudio` Version 0.99.473 32bit for a windows 64bit system with encoding `UTF-8` I am trying to run the R function `createNumericalValues` below, which transforms string factor levels (e.g. income levels) from the `dat` file into numeric values (income integer) and saves it in the `datN` file. The `dat` file was read in advance by using a `UTF-8` encoding.

```
createNumericalValues<- function(dat){
datN=dat
level$X9=factor(levels=c("über 5.000 €", "4.500 bis 5.000 €", "4.000 bis 4.500 €", "3.500 bis 4.000 €", "3.000 bis 3.500 €", "2.500 bis 3.000 €", "2.000  bis 2.500 €", "1.500 bis 2.000 €", "unter 1.500 €"))
for (i in 1:ncol(dat[1:117])){    
if (is.factor(dat[,i])){
if (length(setdiff(levels(dat[,i]),levels(level$X9)))==0){

        labelsVec=c(5500,4750,4250,3750,3250,2750,2250,1750,1000)
        datN[,i]<-   factor(dat[,i], 
                          levels=levels(level$X9),
                          labels=labelsVec)
        datN[,i]<-    as.numeric(levels(datN[,i]))[datN[,i]]
      }}}
return(datN)
}
```

If the factor string includes a Euro Sign (€) the column is not refactored correctly, ONLY if I run the function `createNumericalValues` within another script (e.g. main.R). If I run the code of function `createNumericalValues` itself, without sourcing it, the refactoring works fine. 
How is this possible and how can I make sure, that the refactoring also works, if I source the function?

Comment: **How** are you running the code, if not by sourcing? Via the “Run” or “Source” button?

Comment: I was using the run selection functionality. By trying `source` I now figured out, that this way the function is sourced with the parameter `encoding='UTF-8'`. When sourcing the function in the `main.R` file with this argument, everything works fine. I thought by setting the encoding in the project options, everything will be encoded using `'UTF-8'` - now I know better, thanks!

Comment: Hm, that actually sounds like a bug in RStudio. Maybe report it? RStudio **should** use UTF-8 for its sourcing functionality (*especially* when you’ve set that as a project option), everything else is madness.